# I am having trouble running my app

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently created an app which calculates if a number is a prime or not. The problem is when I run the app, the whole screen is blank(I have added constraints, so that should not be the problem) as if I had not done anything. I tried the command+T in hopes that would help and that did not help.There were also no runtime issues when I checked back in Xcode. Any ideas of what is going on?If I you want my code or want me to be more specific please reply back.Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if text.text != nil{

            var isPrime = true

            let number = Int(text.text!)

            var i = 2

            while i < number!{
                if number! % i == 0{
                    isPrime = false
                    i += 1
                }


                if isPrime{
                    label.text = "\(number) is Prime"
                    label.textColor = UIColor.black
                }else{
                    label.text = "\(number) is not Prime"
                    label.textColor = UIColor.black
                }
             }
         } else{
            label.text = "Error-Enter a positive integer"
            label.textColor = UIColor.red
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's impossible to help unless you give us more information. What are you doing in your app delegate class?

Comment: I'm not sure what an app delegate class is

Comment: In your project navigator (the panel showing your files in the left side of Xcode), you should see a file named AppDelegate.swift. That contains a method thats called when your app is first launched. But since you don't know what it is I'm assuming that you haven't changed it. Can you give us any more clues as the code you have written to calculate prime, where its called and what class it's in?

Comment: I keep getting this error message:Could not attach to pid : “7635”

Comment: Here's my code:

Comment: var isPrime = true
        
            let number = Int(text.text!)
            
            var i = 2
            
            while i < number!{
                if number! % i == 0{
                    isPrime = false
                    i += 1
                }
            
            
                if isPrime{
                    label.text = "\(number) is Prime"
                    label.textColor = UIColor.black
                }else{
                    label.text = "\(number) is not Prime"
                    label.textColor = UIColor.black
                }

Comment: I can also give you a screenshot

Comment: Could you add the code and any screen shots into the main question? Comments aren't great for displaying code and get collapsed away once there are too many to display.

Comment: Your code looks broken to me, but that should not be the root of your issue. Is the blanc screen white or black?

Comment: The screen is white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic Solution after seeing your code is you just removed your baseViewController and added new controller.
So set your Controller as initial controller and you will get your output.

Check this out it's selected for your view controller.

[image]

if this is not your solution upload more data of your problem
thanks.